# Conversion into prenex conjunctive normal form

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, first-order-logic

I'm trying to convert $\forall x \exists y(P(x, y) \rightarrow (\neg\exists z \exists yR(z, y) \wedge \neg\forall xS(x)))$ into PCNF, but am getting stuck at the end.

$\equiv \forall x \exists y(\neg P(x, y) \vee (\forall z  \neg\exists yR(z, y) \wedge \forall x \neg S(x)))$
$\equiv \forall x \exists y(\neg P(x, y) \vee (\forall z  \forall y \neg R(z, y) \wedge \forall x \neg S(x)))$
$\equiv \forall x \exists y(\neg P(x, y) \vee \forall z  \forall y (\neg R(z, y) \wedge \neg S(x)))$
$\equiv \forall x \exists y(\forall z  \forall y (\neg P(x, y) \vee \neg R(z, y) \wedge \neg S(x)))$

I applied the following rules:
$x \rightarrow y \equiv \neg x \vee y$
$\neg\exists xF \equiv \forall x \neg F$
$(\forall xF) \vee G \equiv \forall x(F \vee G)$

Namely I don't know how to resolve the outer $\exists Y$ with the inner $\forall Y$. Guessing I did something wrong in the intermediate steps. What am I missing?

Comment: You made a mistake in the transition to the last line. The law $(\forall x F) \vee G \equiv \forall x(F \vee G)$ only holds if $x$ doesn't occur free in $G$! But in your case, it does. You should better rename the bound variables of the inner two quantifiers $\forall x \forall y$ first, then you can apply the rule. And be aware that $\neg P(x,y) \vee \neg R(z,y) \wedge \neg S(x)$ in your last line should read $\neg P(x,y) \vee (\neg R(z,y) \wedge \neg S(x))$, so you will need distributivity. Finally, was it purposeful that $z$ is not bound?

Comment: @DeeDuu I feel silly, the inner $\exists x$ was supposed to be $\exists z$. (Edited the question to reflect this.) Just to be certain: After renaming $y$ to $p$ or something, this would allow me to basically move everything out within the next two steps because now everything is bound correctly?